# AWS Cognito user-session data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, usersession

I configured AWS Cognito with Microsoft AD. I configured Cognito into aws ingress load-balancer for my website. so I want to get data on users spending time on my website, how to get it?

**ingress.yaml file**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: <ingress_name>
  namespace: <namespace_name>
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-idp-cognito: <cognito_id>
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-on-unauthenticated-request: authenticate
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-scope: openid
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-session-cookie: <session_cookie_id>
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-session-timeout: "3600"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: cognito
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: cognito-auth
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80},{"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: <public_subnet_IP>
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: <certificate_arn>                        
spec:
  ingressClassName: "alb"
  rules:
    - host: <my_host_domain>
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            service:
              name: <service_name>
              port:
                number: 3000
          path: /
          pathType: Prefix
```

This file was working perfect, but how to get user-session data (which user spend-maximum-time on my webiste).